# WPF Treeview, Repositories, Hierarchical data and a WPF newbie

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

Let me start off by saying I've not used WPF or Silverlight in anger before, my only ex other than doing a view simple tutorials back in 2009...

What I'm trying to do is display a treeview containing, at the root level a `DataStoreType` class, and under them they're associated `DataStoreEntry` classes...but loaded on-demand.

The classes themselves look something like this:

```
public class DataStoreType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class DataStoreEntry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; } // Link back to the parent DataStoreType
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Imported { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AvailableFrom { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The items come from a series of repositories, they're not in any kind of child collection on the objects themselves, so the calls to get them
need to be made on these repositories.

Ideally, I'd like to get to grips with using the MVVM pattern too...but any help/ examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Kieron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perfect tutorial/ example for my needs was found here.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

Covered View Models and loading on demand.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full answer, just a hint to get you started.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DataStoreTypes}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate
      DataType="{x:Type DataStoreType}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TypeToEntriesConverter}}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate
      DataType="{x:Type DataStoreEntry}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Now, all you got to do is implement an IValueConverter that convert a `DataStoreType` to an `IEnumerable<DataStoreEntry>` an put it in resources under the name *TypeToEntriesConverter*.